# Retrieve XML Subset

Tags: xquery

I got two XML's. XML 1 and xml 2. xml 2 is a subset of XML 1. I Need to get a final XML which has all the values of XML 1 but not XML 2.

Tried converting the XML values to comma separated strings and populate them in array and did string comparisons etc. But it did not work. Moreover, the size of the XML's can be very huge and is not a solution. I need this solved using XQUERY only.

xml1:

```
<root>
   <f>a</f>
   <f>b</f>
   <f>c</f>
</root>
```

xml2:

```
<root>
   <f>b</f>
   <f>c</f>
</root>
```

Required XML: (XML 1 minus XML 2)

```
<root>
   <f>a</f>
</root>
```

Kindly help with this request.

Comment: That is rather a poorly defined problem, one example does not suffice to explain what you want to achieve and how variable and complex your samples can be, whether "order" of nodes matters when you speak about "subsets". So you will need to explain in more detail what the requirements are. Have you looked into XML diff tools like https://www.deltaxml.com/products/compare/xml-compare/?

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. The structure of XMLS are exactly same as depicted above. The order of nodes can be in any order (It can be value "c" first and then value "b" in XML 2 and can be in any order in XML1 as well) In simpler terms, I need the final XML which has all the values of XML1 and no value from XML2. I need to acheive this programatically and not through a tool.

Comment: So the structure is always a root element named `root` with simple child elements named `f` without attributes and with simple text content?

Answer (score 1):

If the input structure is as simple and defined as shown you can simply select `root/f[not(. =  $xml2/root/f)]` to get the `f` children which have no `f` element in the other document with the same value:

```
declare variable $xml2 as document-node() external := document {
<root>
   <f>b</f>
   <f>c</f>
</root>    
};

<root>
{
    root/f[not(. =  $xml2/root/f)]
}
</root>
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/948Fn5m/1

Of course you can load the second document using `doc('xml2.xml')` instead.

Comment: Thank you Martin. But in the fiddle i see there is no reference to XML1 in the code. I see "." in root/f[not(. =  $xml2/root/f)]. Is this "." referring to XML1 ? a bit confused.

Comment: When run run XQuery you have a context item (https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#dt-dynamic-context), in the fiddle this is the first document, relative to that context document the path `root/f` selects the `f` child elements of the `root` root element and of course inside the predicate `root/f[not(. =  $xml2/root/f)]` the dot refers to the `f` element of the step `f` in the path `root/f`. That is basic XPath/XQuery.